# How do I find the (IPMI) IP of a machine that won't turn on?

Tags: networking, motherboard, power-supply, ipmi

Bit of a weird question - but I bought a storage server on an auction a while back. There's no documentation or stickers on the machine, and it will not turn on by pressing the power button. I'm simply trying to turn this machine on. The network lights and PSU lights are all on, so the BMC is most likely on and working.

What I've tried so far:

- Checking the cables of the power button
- Manually jumping the power button pins on the motherboard (I think the power-on by button has been disabled)
- Starting a DHCP server, hoping that the IPMI port would try to fetch an IP. Haven't seen any IP get issued.
- Checking the ETH interface through Wireshark (don't see anything from the machine connected)
- Doing an ARP-scan over common IP ranges (172.16.x.x, 192.168.x.x, 10.0.x.x)

Considering:

- I don't have an RS-232 to USB interface (yet). That would probably allow me to control the server, too..

What would other options be to try to reach the machine and turn it on? I'm going to try a CMOS reset right now.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! After a long while, somehow, I saw an ARP request come through wireshark;

```
Who has 0.0.0.0? Respond to 10.149.129.67
```

and that was the IPMI of that machine.. Neato!